# Run JNLP file from different machine

Tags: java, java-web-start

I'm new to Java Web Start. I have a JNLP file deployed on my tomcat server the code of the file is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://192.168.1.32:9999/" href="JNLPExample.jnlp">

     <information>
          <title>JNLP Example</title>
          <homepage href="http://192.168.1.32:9999/" />
          <description>JNLP Testing</description>
     </information>

     <security>
          <all-permissions/>
     </security>

     <resources>
          <j2se version="1.6+" />
          <jar href="http://192.168.1.32:9999/JNLPExample.jar" />
     </resources>

     <application-desc main-class="JNLPExample" />
</jnlp>
```

The problem is I'm not able to run this JNLP file from other machine. 
can you please suggest me how to run JNLP file on other machine given that I'm able to download the file from other machine using the URL but when I run the JNLP file it gives unable to run the file.

Comment: *"I'm not able to run this JNLP file from other machine"* .. *"it gives unable to run the file."*  To have any hope of helping, we need the ***exact*** message.  What is it?

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saying I am a 'networking idiot', so some of this may be a bit off.  The address 192.168.* is some type of local address, if I remember correctly.   Can you address the server machine from the client machine by the ip address specified in the JNLP file?
If so, then you should be able to open a command prompt and type > javaws  and that should allow you to start the web start client from that client machine.